# When implementing a buffered sink object, how do I know when I'm at the end of the data to be written?

Tags: c++, boost, file-io, iostream

I am modeling a sink-type device that data can be written to. This will be used in the context of writing to 512 byte blocks.

Internal to the sink, bytes are buffered to a 512 byte vector; when full, this buffer is written to a currently selected 512 byte block. The buffer is then emptied and the next block can be written to.

My problem is thus: if the buffer is not at the point of being full, e.g. when there is no more incoming data, how can the remaining contents be successfully flushed? I could of course implement a public flush function but this doesn't feel particularly elegant. Idea:

```
class DataWriter
{

public:

    DataWriter(/* ommitted for brevity */) {}

    typedef char                                   char_type;
    typedef boost::iostreams::seekable_device_tag  category;

    std::streamsize write(char_type const * const buf, std::streamsize const n) const
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            bufferByteForWriting(s[i]);
        }
        return n;
    }

    // to flush any remaining data. Doesn't feel 
    // that elegant
    void flush()
    {
        writeBufferedDataToBlock(m_buffer.size());
    }

private:
    void bufferByteForWriting(char const byte) const
    {
        if(m_buffer.size() == 512) {
            writeBufferedDataToBlock(512);
            std::vector<uint8_t>.swap(m_buffer);
        }
    }

    writeBufferedDataToBlock(unsigned long const count) const
    {
        // omitted for brevity
        // this writes data to a specific block
        // and increments to a new 512 byte block
        // that the next 512 byte chunk of data will be written to
    }

    std::vector<uint8_t> m_buffer;
};
```

Comment: Flushing the buffer in the DataWriter destructor seems a reasonable idea. This can be combined with a public flush method. This is how std::ostream works. It has essentially the same problem.

Comment: Thanks John, that sounds like a good solution. Cheers!

Comment: I wouldn't flush data in the destructor, because a destructor is usually a function that should not fail, but flushing data is something that can fail. So having a public flush() function is the usual way to go, just make sure, that the flush is called on the highest level possible